# How do you terminate a running file in a Windows command prompt using Python?

Tags: python, windows, cmd, automation, command-prompt

For example - I have Test.exe file. Using python script, Opened CMD and did cd (moved to directory path) & Started **Test.exe** file, Now its was running until we did force exit, So Using UI we using this command (CTRL+c) to stop exit the running file But using python automation script how to exit it and Also Need to read the cmd data.

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
import os
os.system("taskkill /im test.exe")
```

or

```
os.system('wmic process where name="test.exe" delete')
```

Comment: It would be good to post also the Python code using the [subprocess module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) instead of the deprecated [os.system](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.system). There can be get with [os.environ](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.environ) the string value of environment variable `SystemRoot` and use the string `"C:\\Windows"` on `null` returned (very unlikely) and concatenate the Windows directory path with the string `"\\System32\\taskkill.exe"` which is next executed with `subprocess.run` and so `cmd.exe` not used at all.

Comment: The `subprocess.run` solution using `wmic.exe` requires the concatenation of the Windows directory path of environment variable `SystemRoot` with the string `"\\System32\\wbem\\wmic.exe"`. I want to add that the usage of `taskkill.exe` with option `/IM` results in sending the [WM_CLOSE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/wm-close) message to __all__ processes with name `test.exe`. So this solution is not good if multiple `test.exe` run often at the same time (`cmd.exe`, `chrome.exe`, `firefox.exe`, etc.).